# Framed BarChart - Bars outside frame

Tags: charts

When I make the following BarChart:

```
BarChart[{{0, 1.91`, 3.34`, 4.18`, 1.39`, 1.78`, 3.63`}}, FrameLabel -> {"", ""},Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic},GridLines -> {None,Table[i*0.5, {i, -20, 20}]},BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 28, FontFamily -> "Arial",Black},BarSpacing -> {0.1, 3},PlotRange -> {All, {1, 5}},AspectRatio -> 0.4,ImageSize -> 800, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]]]
```

There are bars going outside the bottom side of the frame.
How can this be solved?

thanks

Comment: `PlotRange -> {All, {0, 5}}`? Or without changing your options: `PlotRangeClipping -> True`.

Comment: `PlotRangeClipping`  works fine as I do not want to change `PlotRange`. Thanks